# Запросы CURL в Appium

Tags: curl, appium

Хай!
Пользовались ранее древним **Appium** версии **1.4.13**. Во время запущенной сессии на Android девайсе при запросе

```
curl -N http://localhost:4723/wd/hub/status
```

получали ответ вида:

```
{"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"}},"sessionId":"29b3c645-a825-404a-aded-d3c97717abad"}
```

Обновились на Appium **1.6.5**, теперь на тот же запрос получаем ответ:

```
{"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.6.5","revision":null}},"sessionId":null}
```

При этом даже не важно идет сейчас сессия или нет.

Прежде всего интересует **sessionId**. Или какой-либо другой указатель на то, что в данный момент запущена тестовая сессия. У нас есть веб-интерфейс с мониторингом фермы девайсов. Раньше, если удавалось распарсить в ответе sessionId, то ставили напротив девайса пометочку "занят в данный момент" -было удобно. Теперь данный функционал мониторинга отвалился, что нас печалит.

Возможно существуют другие запросы CURL в Appium сервер? Или набор запросов изменился? Можно ли запросить напрямую вожделенный sessionId? Нигде не могу найти доки на эту тему. Рассчитывал в официальных мануалах Appium найти полный список запросов, но там вообще ни слова про curl.

Заранее всем спасибо!